Steps to request oEmbed Read permissions for a Facebook app
I want to render an Instagram post in a web view on a iOS swift app and for that I intend to use the oEmbed Read API which gives me back the HTML that I can render on a webview.
I have created a Facebook app, however, I only have standard access to oEmbed Read API and for my requirements, I need the advanced access.
When I go to request the advanced access, the button is disabled and I see this message:

Based on that message, I try to hit this endpoint in 3 ways:

Via their graph API tool
A cURL request via terminal
Using the FB SDK in my app and making this request

All 3 scenarios give me the same error:
{"error":{"message":"(#10) To use 'oEmbed Read', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'oEmbed Read' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/apps\/review.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,
So to request for oEmbed permissions, I need to hit the API and to hit the API, I need my app to be reviewed - this seems like a cycle / loop / deadlock.
Despite waiting for 24 hours (maybe even 48 hours), the button didn't get enabled.
I've seen some related posts but they didn't really help.
Please can someone suggest the correct steps to get the permissions I need as their documentation is also not clear on the steps.

I find this so confusing too. These docs indicate that we need a consumer app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types), but it needs to have a verified business attached (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/oembed-read#additional-details) This touches on the app review process but it's pretty slim (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed/#app-review). Why so complicated.
